# How to reduce memory increase in MapView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

[image]

I have developed an iPad application wich consists of a `MapView`. 
When I check the memory status of my app using Instruments (allocation tool), I see, when trying to instantiate the `MapView`, that there is a high memory increment.

See the screen that I have attached here.

I'm pretty sure this is regarding the `MapView`.
Project is in iOS 6.1

What might this be happening?